# How to determine variable initialization order in linking function of directive Angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am confused as how to solve the below scenario in Angular js.
I need to draw a graph on load of the page so i am doing it in the linking function of the directive.But I am confused as how to determine the order of variable initialization.In the below example it works as the declared order but it not working it that order in my actual code.

See the example code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rzzPgqz1flFD8dzWRmk5?p=preview)

The first call to drawBarGraph() fails because the variable graphType is not initialized yet.
So,is there any better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/x2TiI4Usa9EN8QkyiWZ9?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.directive('test', function(){

    return{
        restrict:'E', 
        scope:{
            data:'@',
            graphtype:'@graphtype'
        },
        template:'<div></div>',
        link:function(scope,element,attr){
          scope.graphType = attr['graphType'];
          scope.value = attr['data'];

            attr.$observe('graphtype', function(value) {
                if (value) {
                    scope.graphType=value;
                    scope.drawBarGraph()
                  }
            });

            attr.$observe('data', function(value) {
                if (value) {
                    scope.value=value;
                    scope.drawBarGraph()
                }
            });
         scope.drawBarGraph=function()
         {
             if(!scope.value || !scope.graphType)
                  return; //not enough information to proceed maybe log this
             console.log(scope.value);
             console.log(scope.graphType);
         }

        }
    }
})
```

I pulled the variables initially in the link function so if they're set already then they are populated on the scope of the directive.

I also swapped the order of the observes but it is probably best that you actually check if you have all the values set in your function before having it proceed.

Comment: sorry, I down voted your answer by mistake, can you edit your post so I can cancel the down vote ?

Comment: @OXMO456 no big deal did just edit it in case you want to cancel the down-vote